# How to use perf (or any other tool) to find out the execution time of an application function

Tags: linux, performance, profiling, timing, perf

I have a threaded application and I want to know the execution time of the thread function that is in a loop.

Assume:

```
void thread_func() {
    while(1){
       func1();
       func2();
    }
}
```

I want to see how long it is taking the loop to execute and the time needed for func1 and func2 on a running system. Its a production system and I cannot modify the binary. Can perf or any other tool help me profile the timing here ?

Comment: `perf record` / `perf report` can tell you approximately how much time the CPU spent in one function vs. the other, although the `cycles` hardware event has to pick an instruction to blame (out of all the ones in flight in the out-of-order back end) when it fires, so it's not a perfect representation. If they're both really short then their execution could be overlapping and the total time might not be the sum of them running separately. Anyway, `perf report`'s UI works well if you have debug symbols, otherwise it can be a PITA that refuses to display raw asm if it doesn't have function labels

Comment: Is there any other method that's reliable and simpler to use ?

Comment: Default mode of `perf record` in sampling (periodic interruption of your program and storing these events in perf.data, printed with `perf script`). To measure function execution time you need some form of tracing. There are many tools and ways to do tracing, from adding logging with timestamps into source code to dynamic tracepoints. Uprobes may help, they can be combined with some `perf` subcommands: https://opensource.com/article/17/7/dynamic-tracing-linux-user-and-kernel-space or http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2015-06-28/linux-ftrace-uprobe.html